# ExtJS Menu Item with multiple components

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

My objective is to have a [`menuitem`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.menu.Item) of the following form:

```
-------------------------
window1 [ _ ] [ □ ] [ x ]
-------------------------
```

Therefore the question is: can [tools](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Tool) (similar to those we usually have in a window's top-right corner) or standard [buttons](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button) be placed in a menu item?

Comment: tools are only available for Panels. its seems Templates is the way to go..

Answer (score 0):

Using Ext 4.2:

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function() {

    new Ext.menu.Menu({
        items: {
            border: false,
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Foo',
            shrinkWrapDock: true,
            tools: [{
                type: 'close'
            }]
        }
    }).show();

});
```

Comment: Hi, tried [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvzammit/unjL4/1/) with Ext 4.2 - does not work as expected.